Modeling centrifugal distortion with an effective charge distribution
The hamiltonian of a rigid object with a totally symmetric moment of inertia (i.e. a "spherical top") will depend only on the magnitude of its angular momentum.
If we allow the object to slightly distort at high angular momenta, then there will be a slight dependence of the energy on the orientation of the object's angular momentum in the body-frame.
In the adiabatic limit of low angular momenta and high object stiffness, the configuration space remains effectively the space $SO(3)$ of possible object orientations.
The effect of the non-rigidity is to introduce a term $\Delta H$ to the hamiltonian which is no longer invariant to arbitrary body-fixed rotations of the angular momentum $\mathbf{j}$.
Explicitly, the form of $\Delta H$ is to lowest order in $\mathbf{j}$, necessarily of the form [1]
$$
\Delta H \propto j_x^4 + j_y^4 + j_z^4 - 3\left(j_x^2 j_y^2 + j_y^2 j_z^2 + j_z^2 j_x^2\right) + j^2 + \text{h.c.}
$$
Where $\text{h.c.}$ stands for hermitian conjugate and covers the non-commutating (i.e. quantum-mechanical) case.
This perturbation is necessarily symmetric with respect to body-fixed reflections and roto-reflections of the $T_d$ tetrahedral point group.
My question is: is there a rigid charge distribution rotating with the object that would imitate this perturbation? If so, what multipole moments must necessarily be nonzero? Which moments must necessarily vanish?
[1] Hecht, K. T. (1961). The vibration-rotation energies of tetrahedral XY4 molecules: Part I. Theory of spherical top molecules. Journal of Molecular Spectroscopy, 5(1), 355–389. https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-2852(61)90102-3
